# iPhone6 View is not displaying properly in iPhone5

Tags: ios, iphone-5, iphone-6-plus

I implemented the application for iPhone 6Plus as target.But when i run that app for iphone5 the images are cutting in width.i have done the searching but i didn't get any solution .

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go to your storyboard, select your view controller and uncheck the auto layout property, it might work.

For a detailed explanation on how to do this, consult this link: https://github.com/cocos2d/cocos2d-x/issues/8545

Comment: am using xibs.When i uncheck the auto layout and size classes also  its not working